# How to pack the products from multiple projects into one nuget without any nuspec file?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

I am using Sdk projects targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. The project structure is:

```
SmokeTests
 |
 +--UITests
 |   |
 |   +--Common
 |
 + NonUITests
     |
     +--Common
```

where:

- the SmokeTests project references both UITests and NonUITests using ProjectReferences
- UITests and NonUITests both reference Common using a ProjectReference
- UITests, NonUITests and Common reference some NuGet packages using PackageReferences
- the SmokeTests project has no source code, but it does have some content files.

I use the SmokeTests project as a roll up project. When I build it, its bin\debug\net472 directory contains all the binaries and symbols I want to have in the nuget package, i.e.:

- The NuGet dependencies of UITests, NonUITests and Common
- The dlls of UITests, NonUITests and Common
- The PDBs

The SmokeTests csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>SmokeTests</PackageId>
    <NoPackageAnalysis>true</NoPackageAnalysis>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>true</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <ContentTargetFolders>content</ContentTargetFolders>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**\*.ps1" Exclude="PSTests\run.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NonUITests\NonUITests.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UITests\UITests.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I also have a Directory.Build.props file:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>

    <Version>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(BuildName), `\d+\.\d+(?:.\d+)?(?:.\d+)?`))</Version>
    <Version Condition="'$(Version)' == ''">1.0.0.0</Version>
    <SourceRevisionId>$(Revision)</SourceRevisionId>
    <Company>My Company, Inc.</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © $([System.DateTime]::Now.Year) by My Company, Inc. All rights reserved.</Copyright>
    <Product>Smoke Tests</Product>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

When I build the solution, the produced SmokeTests.1.0.0.nupkg file does not contain any of the binaries, except the SmokeTests.dll itself. Clearly not what I want.

How can I get everything from bin\debug\net472 into the produced NuGet package **without specifying a nuspec file**?

I can always hack an after build step that would manipulate the nupkg file, but I want a proper way to do it.

**EDIT 1**

Judging by the amount of responses either the question is plain stupid or nobody uses .Net core. Posted it here as well - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aa25cb08-ff95-4d81-b0c3-9c4a395f9999/how-to-pack-the-products-from-multiple-projects-into-one-nuget-without-any-nuspec-file?forum=msbuild

Could it be that SO lost its charm?

**EDIT 2**

I added the following properties to [PublicLib.csproj](https://github.com/dasMulli/AdvancedMSBuildDemos/blob/master/IncludeP2P/PublicLib/PublicLib.csproj) to produce a NuGet package:

```
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
<PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
<NoPackageAnalysis>true</NoPackageAnalysis>
<IncludeBuildOutput>true</IncludeBuildOutput>
<AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
```

And it almost works, here is the content of the `PublicLib.1.0.0.nupkg\lib\netstandard2.0` folder:

[image]

But IncludedLib.pdb is missing.

Comment: Did you read through https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/3891, esp [my comment](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/3891#issuecomment-436339457)?

Comment: I need to check your workaround. The reason I need project references is that the nuget package is to be consumed by octopus, which by design requires all the dependencies inside the NuGet. Now, I know I can use octopack, but that requires nuspec file and octopack itself is another dependency of the build. I want to avoid both. Does it make sense now? If so, could you provide an answer with a code sample, so that I could credit you?

Comment: @MartinUllrich - do you think you could improve your sample to include the pdb of the included project as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after long hours of inspecting the `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets` I have arrived at the following code for my roll up project SmokeTests:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>

    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
    <NoPackageAnalysis>true</NoPackageAnalysis>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>true</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
    <ContentTargetFolders>content</ContentTargetFolders>

    <GenerateNuspecDependsOn>MyCustomizePacking</GenerateNuspecDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyCustomizePacking" Returns="@(NuGetPackInput);@(_BuildOutputInPackage);@(_TargetPathsToSymbols)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <NuGetPackInput Remove="@(BuiltProjectOutputGroupKeyOutput);@(DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupOutput)"/>
      <_BuildOutputInPackage Remove="@(BuiltProjectOutputGroupKeyOutput)"/>
      <_TargetPathsToSymbols Remove="@(DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupOutput)"/>

      <NuGetPackInput Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths);@(AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath)" />
      <_BuildOutputInPackage Include="%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Identity)" >
        <TargetFramework>$(TargetFramework)</TargetFramework>
      </_BuildOutputInPackage>
      <_BuildOutputInPackage Include="%(AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath.Identity)" >
        <TargetFramework>$(TargetFramework)</TargetFramework>
      </_BuildOutputInPackage>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**\*.ps1" Exclude="PSTests\run.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NonUITests\NonUITests.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UITests\UITests.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The only way I could find to pack all my project and package references into the NuGet was to hook into the process through `GenerateNuspecDependsOn` by injecting my target `MyCustomizePacking`. This target does the following:

1. Remove the SmokeTests.dll and SmokeTests.pdb from the relevant item groups, because this is a roll up project with no code on its own, I do not need its dll or pdb inside the package.
2. Include `@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)` and `@(AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath)` in the relevant item groups.

Seems to work,but I am not happy with my implementation. I wish there was better support for this.