# Why is building two targets with msbuild different from building each target separately?

Tags: msbuild

I have a project that imports a certain targets file from a Nuget package. Even though I use PackageReferences I am forced to import this file manually.

(See my other question for details - [How are we supposed to execute package build targets in the new world where nuget packages are consumed through msbuild PackageReference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53674627/how-are-we-supposed-to-execute-package-build-targets-in-the-new-world-where-nuge))

This targets file injects `chromedriver.exe` into the `Content` item group with `CopyToOutputDirectory = PreserveNewest`.

I observe a situation where `chromedriver.exe` **is not** copied to the bin folder when running `msbuild /t:"Restore;Build"`, but it **is** copied when running the two targets separately - `msbuild /t:Restore; msbuild /t:Build`.

Can anyone explain how this happens?

(I killed a good portion of the day learning the difference on my skin, want to know how come?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restore changes the imported project files in the `obj\` directory.

For this to take effect, the project file needs to be re-evaluated entirely, which does not happen when you run the Restore and Build targets in the same invocation.

Use the `-restore` command line switch for MSBuild to run a Restore before the other specified targets in the same command line call. MSBuild will run the Restore, empty its XML caches and re-evaluate the project again when running the requested build.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So, this behaviour I see is only because of the Restore target. If I take any other two targets, then I should not witness any difference in behaviour, right?

Comment: Yes. As long as they don't conflict.. `-t:Clean;Publish -p:NoBuild=true` won't be a good combination for example