# msbuild PackageReference.PrivateAssets = All does not seem to work

Tags: msbuild

I have a test project which reference NUnit3TestAdapter. I do not this reference to  be copied over to the projects that depend on this one.

I thought setting PrivateAssets = All would do it, but apparently I misunderstand how it works, because it does not have the desired effect.

Here is the code:

**Rollup\Rollup.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UITests\UITests.csproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**UITests\UITests.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.11.2">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Directory.Build.rsp**

```
.\Rollup.sln /restore /v:m
```

After I run `msbuild` all is built, but I can see NUnit3TestAdapter is in the bin folder for Rollup.

What am I missing?

(https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3996)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrivateAssets` works as expected but the NUnit test adapter NuGet package adds an MSBuild target to the build that adds a few dll files as content items to the project, which then flow transitively through the build - this has the same effect as if you added a text file and set its "Copy to Output Directory" property.

The `NUnit3TestAdapter.props` contains definitions like:

```
<Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll">
  <Link>NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <Visible>False</Visible>
</Content>
```

You should see these files if you click the "Show All Files" in the Visual Studio solution explorer.

Note that test projects aren't really supposed to be packaged or referenced. They should be leaf projects. The test project templates even contain an `<IsPackable>false</…>` definition and XUnit's core package also adds it as an imported MSBuild file. The test frameworks expect you to use their abstraction libraries and not runtime assemblies / test adapter packages for projects that share tests or test logic.

Comment: So, how do I fix the situation? I have to reference NUnit3TestAdapter, otherwise the test is not runnable from Visual Studio. Are you saying there is nothing I can do, because the package is structured in this way?

Comment: Yes.. or don't reference test projects from other projects. If you want to execute tests on other machines, you can still publish the test project and use `dotnet vstest` in the output directory, provided you have referenced `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`.

Comment: I do not think I get it. I want to pack the test projects into one NuGet because it is used by Octopus. For that I created a roll up project that references them all. I do not understand what is the alternative.

Comment: Octopus recommends to use octo pack instead of NuGet for these project types

Comment: That is correct. I was trying to achieve the same goal with less dependencies. Plus I do not like the idea of creating a nuspec file, because I could never avoid duplicating some of the configuration in there with the configuration in msbuild.

Comment: So, bottomline - do not use built-in support, use octopack. Right?

Comment: yes. NuGet packages are meant for sharing code / libraries, not necessarily deployment.publishing tools (`<PackAsTool>`) is different. one could write targets that create custom layouts, even based on the publish output, but that still doesn't solve your NUnit problem.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. Would you mind having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854425/i-am-confused-about-the-role-of-nuget-exe-in-the-world-where-its-functionality-i ?