# I am confused about the role of nuget.exe in the world where its functionality is integrated into msbuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

Given:

1. To consume NuGet packages we use PackageReference in msbuild.
2. To produce NuGet packages we use the `pack` msbuild target.
3. To push NuGet packages we can use the `dotnet nuget push` command.

Plus nuget.exe does not seem to be installed by any of the standard build tooling.

So, what is its role?

Now, I suspect there are still simple chores we cannot do without it. For example, I noticed `dotnet nuget push` pushes nupkg into a flat file structure, so, if I want a hierarchical one I probably need to use `nuget add`. But I am not sure.

So, actually two questions:

1. What is the role of nuget.exe in the new world?
2. Is `nuget.exe add` the only way to publish a nuget package to a hierarchical source?

Comment: Its main role is for legacy projects or complex situations MSBuild cannot handle. For example, if you want to further customize the NuGet packages generating by MSBuild, you can use your own package specification file and then ˋnuget pack`.

Comment: I accept that. But I have a rather simple scenario of pushing to a hierarchical source. Can I do it without nuget?